# How to set and check for no-value as enumerate?

Tags: delphi, enums, delphi-xe7

I'm converting some of the common values into enumerated values. But I have a problem with those where missing value/no-value also has meaning:

```
vDataType:string;

If vDataType = '' Then // no datatype assigned, yet -> handle appropriately
else if vDataType = 'PROJECT' then // process as project record
else if vDataTpye = 'GROUP' then // process as project group record
else if vDataType = 'TASK' then // process as project task
```

If I now set :

```
TDataType = (dtProject, dtGroup, dtTask);

var vDatatype:TDataType;
```

I can use

```
If vDataType = dtProject Then ...
else if vDataType = dtGroup then ...
else if vDataType = dtTaks then ...
```

but since first element is dtProject as 0, how can I now check for no value, to replace: `if vDatatype = '' then...`

The records are all in same array, so no-value has meaning as it differentiates records from others that were marked as Project, Group or Task. The records are marked in the process of importing records and I would like to avoid setting one of the enum values, like dtNone, to all records that are not dtProject, dtGroup or dtTask.

**EDIT:**

Here is example where I got stuck:

```
TData = record
    LineID:integer;
    FullLine:string;
    //...
    DataType:string;
end;

var vArray:TArray<TData>;

procedure ProcessDataAfterImport;
var i:integer;
begin
  for i:=0 to High(vArray) do
  begin
    if Copy(vArray[i].FullLine,1,4)='PRJ=' then
        vArray[i].DataType := 'PROJECT'
    else if Copy(vArray[i].FullLine,1,4)='GRP=' then
        vArray[i].DataType := 'GROUP'
    else if Copy(vArray[i].FullLine,1,4)='TSK=' then
        vArray[i].DataType := 'TASK';
  end;
end;

procedure ProcessProjects;
var i:integer;    
begin
  for i:=0 to High(vArray) do
  if vArray[i].DataType = 'PROJECT' Then
     ParseProjectRecord(vArray[i]);
end;
```

And I have lot's of similar methods as ProcessProjects that process records based on DataType and I wanted to not use 'PROJECT' everywhere but enums, which are integers and I assume also faster and not prone to mistakes like 'PROJCET'. I counted 'PROJECT' is used 55 times. 'GROUP' and 'TASK' little less, but then I have other examples that use similar string values to designate record type.

Comment: It's hard to tell. You want to sanitize strigly-typed input with enum, yet you want to retain a flexibility of null values. Please pick one.

Comment: You've defined an enum with three possible values. If you want to check for *four* possible states, then you'll need at least *four* possible values. Three is not enough.

Comment: What I usually do is make the first (or last) member of the enum equivalent to none. In the case of your enum, it could be `TDataType = (dtNone, dtProject, dtGroup, dtTask);`, and then your case could end with `else vDataType := dtNone;`.

Comment: @KenWhite: OK, this makes sense. This means I will need to replace `If vArray[i].DataType = '' Then...` with `If vArray[i].DataType = dtNone The...`, correct? This makes sense and it understandable.

Comment: @RobKennedy: Yes, as I can see in Ken White's comment, a _fourth_ possible value could be `dtNone`. Is that what you had in mind?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Note you don't have to use `dtNone`; it was just an example. You could use anything you want that makes your code clear (`dtUnknown`, maybe). And yes, that's what @Rob was saying - it's the fourth possible value for your enum.

Comment: It makes sense, as it is set as first enum value, will have value as 0, and since this is global array, not local, every DataType filed in every record will default to 0. Yes, I understand the actual naming is not important - what is important is that it makes sense as default, not-set value, different from any other value defined in process methds.

Comment: Why do you keep assuming what `0` ordinal is more special than the others?

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain it correctly... I have lots of records and no-value (empty string) means that the record is not one of the categories. So it is a 'no category' record. Useful when I need to process these records. And now with enums, these records will default to 0 - dtNone and I will be able to quickly change the code from comparing string DataType =/<> '' to DataType =/<> 0. Right? So, i don't need to set 0 to DataType because its set 0 by default. Right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you appear to be asking for is not possible.

It is difficult to say without seeing more of the code involved in your case but I suspect that the use of an empty string - whether by accident or design - was exploiting the fact that strings are one of the few types in Delphi that are initialised by the runtime when declared as local variables.  This also includes - for example - interface references and dynamic arrays.

This special treatment of these types for local variables is necessary because the runtime treats these types in special ways that rely on the certainty that variables of these types are in a valid initial state.

e.g. the **Length** field in the RTTI of a `String` *must* correctly reflect the memory allocated to hold the chars in that string otherwise memory errors will result when that string is modified.  An interface must be NIL to avoid an invalid call to **Release** when initially assigned some other value.  etc etc

Values of *other* types declared as class member variables, for example, may *appear* to be initialised in new instance of a class but this is the result of the zero-ing of memory for newly allocated instances of those classes, rather than any actual initialisation as such.

The problem when changing from a `String` to an enum is that enums do not require (and therefore do not receive) any such special treatment and so *must* be initialised explicitly.

**NOTE:** Even if enums were auto-initialised they would be initialised to `0` (zero), i.e. the first member of the enum (unless that first member has been explicitly assigned a non-zero ordinal value).

With that in mind, this means that if enum variables are required to be able to indicate `No Value` or `Not Set` then this **must** be present as a valid value in the enum itself and you must explicitly initialise variables of that type as appropriate.

**NOTE:** If you ensure that this `Not set` value is the first member of the enum then it will, as you have observed, have the value `0` (zero) which means that any class member variables of this type will be automatically "initialised" with this `Not set` value in new instances of that class.

But for *local* variables, *record members* etc, you will have to initialise it explicitly, just as you would have to initialise an `Integer` or a `Boolean` etc etc.

Comment: Correct, I relied on empty string as a value distinct from others, so no-value , empty string, also meant that it is specific type of record, which didn't need to be set - if default value.

Comment: Right, so there is unfortunately no escaping the fact that you need a value in the enum that is also distinct from the others in that enum but, unlike a string, initialisation will not be automatic.  Strings are only a special case when it comes to initialisation for reasons specific to that data type which don't apply to enums.  So you have to give up (some) auto-initialisation but you gain efficiency (including the ability to CASE on the values) and robustness (type/value safety among others as you identified).  Whether that trade is worth it is up to you.  :)

Answer (score 4):

In Delphi, you can set the value of the enum. For example you can write:

```
TDataType = (dtNone=-1, dtProject, ...);
```

which may deal with your problem of assigning `0` to `dtNone`.

However, as others have said, it's hard to see where this leads without more code. At the moment, it's not obvious whether enums will make any difference instead of strings.

Comment: Scratch "and Pascal", **explicit ordinality** is relatively modern non-standard feature.

Comment: FreeConsulting, thanks for this. I edited the comment.

Answer (score 3):

You could use potentionaly dangerous approach of

```
If vDataType = dtProject Then ...
else if vDataType = dtGroup then ...
else if vDataType = dtTaks then ...
else // no predefined datatype assigned, yet -> handle appropriately
```

where the final else will be executed whenever none of the previous if and else if conditions were met.

Now why is this potentially dangerous?

As Deltics already explained in his answer *local variables, record members etc* are not initialized to some default state but have only assigned certain memory location to them it is possible that memory data that was stored at that location from previously being assigned to something might contain data which would translate into one of your `set` values even if you haven't assigned it.

So I would still suggest you define default set value and assign it every time when none of the others is to be assigned.

Comment: Thank you, but you are right, as from other comments, we can see this is not good approach. I relied on empty string as default value - absent of all other values - so, specific record type. I always compared `If vArray[i].DataType = '' then..`.